# Slumber Python library fails when I try to make get call when URL had dashes(-)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using python's slumber library to make HTTP call to a service. This is how it looks. I need to make get request for this URL https://sample-billing-api.test/2/billing-accounts?id=2169.

When I run this I get error NameError: name 'accounts' is not defined.

```
import slumber

class ParseAuth(AuthBase):
def __call__(self, r):
    r.headers['x-api-key'] = '<API KEY>'
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r

api = slumber.API('https://sample-billing-api.test/2/', append_slash=False, auth=ParseAuth())
response = api.billing-accounts.get(id=2169)
```

api.billing-accounts.get(id=2169) line doesn't work.

One solution is to switch to python request package as do something like this. This approach works. But I need to use slumber package as I have been using Slumber package for all my API calls. Also I have written decorators to handle slumber response.

```
import requests
        headers = {
        'x-api-key': '<api_key>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    with requests.session() as s:
        res = s.get(
            'https://sample-billing-api.test/2/billing-accounts?id=2169',
            headers=headers
        )
        s.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seem not be friendly to an url with `-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  solution worked finally...

```
import slumber
class ParseAuth(AuthBase):
   def __call__(self, r):
       r.headers['x-api-key'] = '<API KEY>'
       r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
       return r

 api = slumber.API('https://sample-billing-api.test/2/', append_slash=False, 
 auth=ParseAuth())
 response = getattr(self.api, "billing-accounts").get(id=2169)
```